# Evaluating $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}$

Tags: analysis

I'm trying to find and prove the value of$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

I was thinking that since
$$\frac{1}{n}(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}} = \frac{1}{n} \left[ (1)^{\frac{1}{n}}(2)^{\frac{1}{n}}...(n)^{\frac{1}{n}}  \right]$$

and we know that 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}n^{\frac{1}{n}} = 1$$
and 
$$k^{\frac{1}{n}} \leq  \ n^{\frac{1}{n}} \ \ \ \ \forall k \leq n$$

So $(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}} \leq 1 \ \forall n \ $* Then it is bounded. We also know that $\lim \frac{1}{n} =0$, therefore 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}} = 0 **$$

I'm pretty sure this line of reasoning is ok. Now proving it is another thing. Any suggestions?

*I realize now that this statement is not true, but that did not get me any closer to solving the problem. I do believe that it is bounded though.

**LOL, I don't believe this to be true anymore either, a wild guess tells me that the solution may be $\frac{1}{e}$

Comment: if you use [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) $n! \sim \frac {n^n}{e^n}\sqrt {2 \pi n}$ you get a different result.

Comment: @Ross That technique is beyond the scope of my class.

Comment: From Ross' comment you can deduce that the limit does not exist because the sequence has no upper bound. So you should try to show this.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28476/finding-the-limit-of-frac-n-sqrtnn).

Comment: I found the solution, here is a  [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1327589/322933) in case you are interested. @kobe uses the theorem I'm interested in for his second solution

Comment: @miracle173:  the limit does exist and it is $\frac 1e$.  The $n$th root  takes the leading fraction to $\frac ne$, then dividing by $n$ gives $\frac 1e$.  The square root term goes to $1$ because of the $n$th root.

Comment: I missed the $\frac{1}{n}$ factor in the expression.